# A note making feature in the personal page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I would love a simple, personal notes taking feature. Not for everything on this page, but just on my personal page. Just for me to take some personal notes about stuff on this page, some useful metaqueries, links related to this site, etc.

I know I could use bookmarks, but those are only local to the browser, and I use the site from different places a lot, and so, for taking notes about a page, the page itself is the most logical location.

And it's only one extra column in the user table, so I shouldn't take too long for you to develop :))

Comment: Last line like that sounds like you've posted "jobs" to eLance and vWorker type sites before

Comment: This sounds like a job that can be solved by the user locally using one of thousands of extensions or tools, no need to add complexity to the site. (or maybe a sidewiki)

Comment: I actually like this idea. Something private to keep on the site - like a meta - but off my private profile (which would be the only place to store free text)

Comment: The last line was more like a joke... but I regred it if I see the votes of this question. I believed you would understand the smiley.

Comment: What's wrong with all the other places you can keep reminders?  Gmail... Back of your hand... Dropbox...etc....

Comment: @Lix What's wrong with having this? I felt it would be convenient to have information pertaining to SE to be on, well... SE.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense if SO or any other random website provides such functionality. It is in fact much more usable to have a central place for your notes, like some browser extension or something.

Comment: If it's going to be private then why not just use notepad itself? I like to keep notes so I use a physical notepad. I don't think it would be beneficial on stack overflow.

Comment: I understand your idea but honestly I have to say it would be cluttering SE. I mean, one can think of dozens of other such "tools" to be added to SE.

Comment: I use my profile as a notepad, including quick links to posts I should not forget. Things which I don't want to show to the public are surrounded by `<!--` and `-->`, causing the message to be hidden.

Comment: A feature that makes "notes" accessible by the community is already available as answering your own question. The core idea of SE is that everything is a question with answer(s), and random notes don't quite fit in that philosophy.

Comment: This feature would be super useful to store a list of links you often use when replying to questions (specific RFCs, tools documentation, etc.), even more so if it would be displayed on each question page and/or easily searchable. It would improve the answers given. Browser bookmarks and cloud applications do not solve the problems (see my question for details or the one listed in the Linked box on right with score of -12)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's any number of thousands of cloud applications that do precisely what you are asking: online annotations, sticky notes, Evernote-style note-talking applications.

It's not just a matter of throwing an extra column in the user table. You have a user interface, user will want it to be searchable, editable, add special formatting. No matter what use you have in mind for this feature, there are thousands of users who want a variation of the feature, too.

The bottom line is, for all these *"manage my data"* requests (e.g. advanced favorites/bookmarking, spell checking, note-taking and annotations, etc.), there are third-party tools with dedicated resources that will do the job better. I cannot see the value to duplicating a general-purpose, web-y application specifically for *this* site that is already available (and much more functional) elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps you could suggest some specific tools that IYO cover the OP's needs.

Comment: @belisarius: I've tried various web annotation tools but never *kept* using them. Almost all my note-taking activities go into http://evernote.com.

Comment: I disagree very much for the reasons I have put in my own question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306184/how-to-keep-private-notes-useful-links-per-profile-to-help-answering-questions. ; I do not want to use a cloud application to store information I only need on StackOverflow sites and browser bookmarks do not suit everytime either. Both cases are specifically not useful when using the SO mobile application. As I suggested, this content could be searched from the page you reply to questions, to be able to easily reuse the content.

Answer (score 5):

> **Disclaimer**
>   Of all the people to disagree with this suggestion,  personally, I
>   think I could benefit from something like this I have a **terrible**
>   memory.

What was I doing again?  Oh...that's right... posting on meta....

Why limit this functionality to Stack Overflow?  I'm sure you'd find it hand to store all sorts of data like that.  There are many many many places that provide this functionality - at the "low tech" level, you could even just store some notes in a draft on Gmail...

If the main problem that you are talking about is having to remember things then I'm afraid Stack Exchange is not going to take responsibility for **our** forgetfulness...

---

If you are looking for a less personal opinion then one could argue that the benefits of implementing this kind of feature would not be substantial enough with relation to the effort put in to the development.

Comment: I don't understand the example you gave about the comment replies.  I think, as you are the one suggesting such a feature that you should first make the argument of "`why yes`" before requesting explanations of "`why not`".  So far the only argument you have given in your post was "`...would be nice...`".  That's simply not enough of an argument.  Tell us why the community needs and would benefit from such a feature.

Comment: It would increase ease and fluidity of access to personal information pertaining only to SE. as far as about comments, my point was it increases ease of access, and makes it so we don't need to remember to check back, thus they are already taking responsibility for our forgetfulness. Also thanks for post edit.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can [edit your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current), and insert the personal notes as HTML comment in your About Me section which allows some raw HTML:

> [image: personal notes as HTML comment in About Me section]

Save the profile only for that site, and you're good to go. The notes will always be visible in that page, and only for you.

HTML comment is anything between `<!--` and `-->`.

Comment: Anyone watching the HTML source file of your profile will see them, except if they are explicitly filtered out on rendering?

Comment: Also, that is not easily searchable, nor directly available when replying to a question (the main motivations I have put in my question you marked as duplicate just after putting this answer here)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek just checked, they're rendered out server side, meaning they are not part of the HTML source of your public profile. As for searchable/available you're correct, but even with what you have in mind implemented, you'll always have to open the profile page in a different tab anyway, so can't see any big difference.

Comment: No, the same way you have "Linked" or "Related" columns on the right of each question and hence when you reply to one, you could have there (same tab) your own list of links you could easily paste in your answer.