# Notepad feature across StackExchange

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A note making feature in the personal page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79947/a-note-making-feature-in-the-personal-page)

> **Note:** While constructive criticism is nice, I'd like answers with a little more reason of why SE should not implement it, more than why you might personally dislike it (although that's important). If you don't like a specific part or feel a certain part is bad, I would love to hear how I can make it better. If it's just bad, alright. But I'd like to hear what parts are **and** aren't. (I did not just post this without thinking, and I **would** like to improve my idea) I do appreciate that people care enough to post though, and please don't let up on me anytime soon ;).

**My suggestion/request is for a notepad to be included on the site.** This would just be storing information in a simple text format, to be stored on your account across SE. It could possibly be accessed by a link on top of the page, and have a separate div appear to read/write from, without changing the page. I believe this would increase the ease of access / give a more fluid approach across SE sites for storing SE related information.

I got this idea from a text-based game I play. It can be handy for storing simple reminders, something someone mentioned you want to look into later, or maybe even a witty remark or two. While the game I'm referring to allows 5k+ charters, I think even a simple little notepad function would be nice. You could have notepad up, true, but it would be handy when switching accounts / to just have everything in one window.

However, due to performance or space or other factors I have not considered, I would love to hear any constructive criticism (a hard request, I know).

**Note:** I am suggesting this as only something you would be able to view (and would prefer this) across SE sites, but even if it could be accessed by the community (as long as clearly labeled as such), I would alright with that as well if need be (would also be more interesting).

Also, the div for notes that appears could be the kinda that appear at the top of the page, or appear over the page, but would be optional either way (aka, this feature would not be intrusive, and should be no bigger than the 'about' button on top of page).

**Edit:**

First I know there's a lot of tools for 'taking notes'. However this request is about adding the feature to SE. While I realize the fact that "there are alternatives" is a valid argument, my argument is the alternatives are not official SE sources, and are all less convenient to use, especially if you only have one screen and use this on two computers.

---

As Rob W mentioned, you can put something in your profile surround with `<!-- and -->`. My idea is such that rather than such a work around, you could have this information easily accessible on every page. Even the fact people would possibly use this is to me a reason this would be worth implementing.

---

> **Q:** What's wrong with all the other places you can keep reminders? Gmail... Back of your hand... Dropbox...etc.... – Lix

**A:** While each of these you could access on different computers and SE sites, I feel this would be more convenient. If this makes the site more convenient for some, why not? It would make information more accessible without being an inconvenience to those who don't use it, but be much appreciated by those who do.

---

> **Q:** I don't think it makes sense if SO or any other random website provides such functionality. It is in fact much more usable to have a central place for your notes, like some browser extension or something. – pimvdb

**A:** Yet a lot of 'random websites' have this ability. And While it may be more useful to some to have all their notes in one place, I know I personally prefer to put all my info in tons of folders on the computer, and similarly, would love to be able to access SE information on SE. Again I must ask, why not? You've given me other ways to do it, but I obviously did not prefer them if I posted this (not to be rude).

---

> **Q:** If it's going to be private then why not just use notepad itself? I like to keep notes so I use a physical notepad. - ThePower

**A:** It would allow better availability towards accessing personal stored data pertaining directly to SE.

---

> **Q:** I understand your idea but honestly I have to say it would be cluttering SE.

**A:** How would it clutter SE? SE already has a ton of feature designed to make the site better, and would not be intrusive if you choose not to use it, should be no bigger than any other link on top of page (could even be put to the left of your name to separate it).

---

> **Q:** ...one could argue that the benefits of implementing this kind of feature would not be substantial enough with relation to the effort put in to the development. - Lix

**A:** As far as storing information, it would be no harder than storing profile information. As far as accessing without page changing, getting the information should be no harder than clicking the arrow next to your name at top of page getting data related to you. As far as editing, again should be similar to profile. (Although I could be missing something)