# How to keep private notes/useful links (per profile) to help answering questions?

Tags: feature-request

While answering questions, adding comments and even more during reviews or edits, I often find myself in the need to quote some external reference, that I know of without remembering the exact URL. Some are often needed, like RFC2606 or RFC6302 for tokens to use in obfuscation, or various software documentation, etc.

It would be handy if I could have a page, in my profile, completely private, where I could basically fill out a free-form text box where in my case I could put my "most needed links". Already like that it would be useful, as tied to my account, and a further improvement would be if it could be made available in some way at the time we are on a question, like with a small search text box that would hit this page or something like that.

Of course I can reach almost the same goal by having all the resources as bookmarks in my browser (which is what I am doing right now failing to have a better solution), but it would be more convenient to have them in each Stack Overflow site (because I may use different computers/browsers that are not necessarily linked on the bookmarks-level together, or using the Stack Overflow  mobile application, etc. and I may not like using a cloud application for that).

I am also open to suggestions from other active participants that have the same problem and how they solve it, as I may have missed obvious ways to do that.

**Update 1**:
Ok for the duplicate question, I have searched before posting, but this question with a score of -9 never popped up in results. The answers there do not 100% answers my question anyway...

**Update 2**:
Let me re-emphasize again that the core idea is to store a list of links that I often need when replying to questions on Stack Overflow. It is not for storing unrelated texts. And even better if they are easily available when answering questions.

Comment: sounds similar to this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76759/private-notes-on-questions

Comment: No, I looked at it before posting, because in my case it would be only one page/form tied to your profile (like there is already private parts in your profile), not one private field per question (this latter case seems useless to me). The purpose is really just to have repeating URLs typically easily accessible to use them when replying. It is to help replying, not to use SO sites as private scratchpad.

Comment: Browser favorites.

Comment: @Won't : already discussed in my question, what you do when using multiple computers/browsers not synced? Or answering from the mobile application for that matter? And when the concerned links are not useful outside of SO, so not useful as local bookmarks?

Comment: @Shadow Please see my two updates

Comment: @PatrickMevzek still duplicate. Original question score isn't relevant, and new answers can always be posted there, so having "wrong" answers isn't reason enough as well.

Comment: @Shadow I was telling about the score to explain I haven't seen the other question when I searched before posting (it did not pop up I suspect due to its score)... I still believe that my question is different enough as stated in Update2 (speaking of list of links instead of text, adding easy way to reuse them from editing/answering questions), but I certainly do not seem to see a lot of traction for this idea, which is unfortunate as I believe it could help people answering doing a better job.

Comment: I fully agree with all the details in this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137545/notepad-feature-across-stackexchange (that did not appear earlier when searching for the topic before posting). Too bad it got merged (but I do not see how/its effects) and locked.